# Необходимо найти разницу двух дат и получить ответ в днях, подскажите, почему выдаёт NaN?

Tags: javascript

```js
let somedate1 = (date1, date2) => {
  const [day, month, year] = date1.split('.').map(Number);
  const [days, months, years] = date2.split('.').map(Number);
  let firstDate = new Date()[year, month - 1, day];
  let secondDate = new Date()[years, months - 1, days];
  let diffDate = (secondDate - firstDate) / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
  return diffDate;
}

console.log(somedate1('05.05.2005', '10-10-2020'));
```

Comment: Вторая дата не в том формате. Создание даты неверно по синтаксису - надо передавать данные в конструктор, а не рядом. Нет округления. Посмотрите на возможности `console.log()`, он вам много тайн расскажет при отладке кода

Answer (score -1):

На самом деле все просто. если запустить этот код

```
let somedate1 = (date1, date2) => {
  const [day, month, year] = date1.split('.').map(Number);
  const [days, months, years] = date2.split('.').map(Number);
  let firstDate = new Date([year, month - 1, day]);
  let secondDate = new Date([years, months - 1, days]);
  let diffDate = ((secondDate - firstDate) / 1000) * 3600 * 24;
  console.log(firstDate, ' ', secondDate);
  return diffDate;
};

console.log(somedate1('05.05.2005', '10-10-2020'));
```

то выведет

```
2005-04-04T20:00:00.000Z   Invalid Date
NaN
```

Проблема явно во втором.

В

```
console.log(somedate1('05.05.2005', '10-10-2020'));
```

Вторую дату вы вводите через "-", а разделение делаете по ".".

Рабочий код будет выглядеть так:

```
let somedate1 = (date1, date2) => {
  const [day, month, year] = date1.split('.').map(Number);
  const [days, months, years] = date2.split('-').map(Number);
  let firstDate = new Date([year, month - 1, day]);
  let secondDate = new Date([years, months - 1, days]);
  let diffDate = ((secondDate - firstDate) / 1000) * 3600 * 24;
  console.log(firstDate, ' ', secondDate);
  return diffDate;
};

console.log(somedate1('05.05.2005', '10-10-2020'));
```

Вывод:

```
2005-04-04T20:00:00.000Z   2020-09-09T21:00:00.000Z
42080290560000
```

Или так:

```
let somedate1 = (date1, date2) => {
  const [day, month, year] = date1.split('.').map(Number);
  const [days, months, years] = date2.split('.').map(Number);
  let firstDate = new Date([year, month - 1, day]);
  let secondDate = new Date([years, months - 1, days]);
  let diffDate = ((secondDate - firstDate) / 1000) * 3600 * 24;
  console.log(firstDate, ' ', secondDate);
  return diffDate;
};

console.log(somedate1('05.05.2005', '10.10.2020'));
```

Вывод:

```
2005-04-04T20:00:00.000Z   2020-09-09T21:00:00.000Z
42080290560000
```